# Unable to display the output string

Tags: c++

I am writing a basic code to perform some operations on strings. When I try to run my program, it hangs and doesnt give the output. Can anyone pl point out the error, and recommend necessary changes/optimization. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
int main(){

int i=0,j=0;

string ch,out;
cin>>ch;

while(ch[i]!='\0'){
string dot=".";
if(ch[i]=='A'||ch[i]=='E'||ch[i]=='I'||ch[i]=='O'||ch[i]=='U'
||ch[i]=='a'||ch[i]=='e'||ch[i]=='i'||ch[i]=='o'||ch[i]=='u'){
    i++;
    break;
    }
    else{
    if(isupper(ch[i])){
        out+=dot;
        out+=tolower(ch[i]);
    }
    else {out+=dot;
        out+=ch[i];
    }

    }
    }
cout<<out;


}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error you are receiving?

Comment: `out.append(1, ch[i])`. Or simply `out += ch[i];`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for the edit. my program compiles fine now, but it doesnt display the output  ?

Comment: @user3576010 When you edited the question you replaced it for a new question. Please don't do that as comments and answers might reflect the original version. Better to leave it as is and either post a new question with the remaining problem, or ask for further clarifications in a comment.

Comment: @user3576010 also, I think the issue is that you never exit the while loop as you never increment `i` unless it triggers the if-block. You need to advance `i` otherwise too, or you'll never reach the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) for`std::basic_string::append` you'll see that the only version of the function that takes a single character as its argument is:

```
basic_string& append( size_type count, CharT ch );
```

and that also expects`size_type count`specifying how many characters to append to the string.

In your case, as you just want to append one single character you should use:

```
out.append(1, ch[i]);
```

and

```
out.append(1, tolower(ch[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a `char` using `out.append`. If you want to add single character, try

> `out.append(1, ch[i]);`